# What is the method to do docker backup?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I use Docker Community Edition (CE) and run on my centos 7.4

I just would like to ask if I would like to backup the docker, container.

Now, I have backup full directory which related to docker.

I also find it in the web, there are many method to export container for backup, but it requires to update the backup list of container ( because there will be new docker, container will be created on and on ), otherwise, the new container, docker will not be backup.

Therefore, I would like to ask is there  a good method to backup full directory?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to make sure there's nothing of actual importance in a running container and nothing that lives only in `/var/lib/docker`.  That means:

- When you start a container, make sure the actual command is recorded somewhere (like a shell script or a Docker Compose YAML file) and checked into source control.
- Never "exec into a container and install software".  Learn the `Dockerfile` system, use `docker build` to create custom images, and check the `Dockerfile`s into source control.  If you can, push the actual images to some repository server (Docker Hub, AWS ECR, something you run yourself).
- Design your application to not need storage in the container if at all possible.  A "remote" database (could be in another container; could be on a dedicated server) is common.  This both helps the backup situation and makes it easier to run multiple copies of a container.
- If your container does have persistent storage (maybe it is the database) use `docker run -v` to give it a location on the host system outside the Docker tree.
- Never use `docker commit`; if you need to change an image, update the `Dockerfile`, check it in, and rebuild the image.

If all of this works, then you can lose all of `/var/lib/docker` and it won't matter.  You should be able to test this by launching a new VM and recreating your system state there.  Having proven this to yourself, exclude `/var/lib/docker` from backups, because it's large and contains only data you can reproduce and reload.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to [`commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) your `Containers` and create `Docker Images` from them and use [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command to retrieve a tar file for your `Docker Images`. After that you can use [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) command to reload your saved `Docker Images`. This way all the `Containers` you create from your `Docker Image` is a backup from your original `Containers`.

But i thunk more elegant way is to use [`Volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) when creating a `Container`. This way you can create backups from your `Volumes` and later when necessary, you can create `Containers` with `Volumes` mapped to your backups.